# Multiple issues when converted to Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I have got a task to convert a project to Swift 3.0. But I dont have expertise in Swift language. Still I followed some tips and I have converted to Swift 3.0 and got many errors. Was able to fix around 100+ errors and still few are pending. I have done lots of searching but couldn't find any solutions. Someone can help me fix the issues? Don't feel that I am asking direct solutions. I am really stuck and thats why I am asking.

Please let me know if more info is needed.

So, below I am listed down few items which I can't fix so far.

**First:** ***This issue is resolved***

```
self.audioFileStreamID = AudioFileStreamID()
self.audioQueue = AudioQueueRef()
```

For bothe these codes, I am getting error;

> Cannot convert initializer for type 'AudioFileStreamID' with no arguments.

**Second:** ***This issue resolved***

```
let status = AudioFileStreamOpen(self.pointer, AudioFileStreamPropertyListener, AudioFileStreamPacketListener, fileType, &self.audioFileStreamID)
```

Error message:

> Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument. Implicit conversion from 'AudioFileStreamID' to 'AudioFileStreamID?' requires a temporary

**Third:**

```
self.type(of: init)(scheme: scheme, host: host, path: path, credential: credential)
```

Error message:

> Expected expression in list of expressions

```
convenience init(scheme: String, host: String, path: String, credential: URLCredential) {
    let url = NSURL(scheme: scheme, host: host, path: path)!
    self.type(of: init)(url: url, credential: credential) //here also got the same error
}
```

**Update:**
First and Second issues are fixed.

Comment: Anyone has any idea about these issues? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Update your cocoa pods and clear your derive data folder and try to run again.

In xcode 8 derived data folder changed,

Go to File -> Workspace setting -> then see this image,

[image]

Click on -> on path and clear that derived data folder.

Also check if some methods are deprecated in swift 3.0

Comment: I have followed your steps, but still the error is there. :(